# How to get tag_description in foreach Wordpress template?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, tags

I've made this script,

```
<?php
function top_tags() {
    $tags = get_tags();

    if (empty($tags))
        return;

    $counts = $tag_links = array();
    foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
        $counts[$tag->name] = $tag->count;
        $tag_links[$tag->name] = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
    }

    asort($counts);
    $counts = array_reverse( $counts, true );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $counts as $tag => $count ) {
        $i++;
        $tag_link = clean_url($tag_links[$tag]);
        $tag = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', wp_specialchars( $tag ));
        if($i < 11){
            print "<li><a href=\"$tag_link\">$tag ($count) </a></li>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But I can't seem to get the tag_description per tag. It does not show anything if I use `$description = tag_description();` in the foreach function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about... this:

```
<?php
function top_tags() {
    $tags = get_tags();

    if (empty($tags))
        return;

    $counts = $tag_links = array();
    foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
        $counts[$tag->name] = $tag->count;
        $tag_links[$tag->name] = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
    }

    asort($counts);
    $counts = array_reverse( $counts, true );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $counts as $tag => $count ) {
        $i++;
        $tag_link = clean_url($tag_links[$tag]);
        $tag_description = tag_description(get_term_by('name', $tag, 'post_tag')->term_id);
        $tag = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', wp_specialchars( $tag ));
        if($i < 11){
            print "<li><a href=\"$tag_link\">$tag ($count) </a> $tag_description </li>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

A more efficient way of doing this (untested):

```
<?php
function top_tags() {
    $tags = get_tags();

    if (empty($tags))
        return;

    $counts = $tag_links = array();
    foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
        $counts[$tag->name] = $tag->count;
        $tag_links[$tag->name] = array( 'url' => get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ), 'description' => $tag->description);
    }

    asort($counts);
    $counts = array_reverse( $counts, true );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $counts as $tag => $count ) {
        $i++;
        $tag_link = clean_url($tag_links[$tag]['url']);
        $tag_description = $tag_links[$tag]['description'];
        $tag = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', wp_specialchars( $tag ));
        if($i < 11){
            print "<li><a href=\"$tag_link\">$tag ($count) </a> $tag_description </li>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Nope, still seeing nothing. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Did you try it with my edits? tag was changed to "post_tag" in the get_term_by

Comment: Haha brilliant, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Just to comment on your idea, which should not be used, you can use [`tag_description`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/tag_description) inside your `foreach` loop as follow

```
$description = tag_description($tag->term_id);
```

The above method is not wrong, but `get_tags` already returns the tag description which you can return as follow

```
$tag->description
```

**EDIT**

To see what is returned by `get_tags`, do the following

```
$tags = get_tags;
?><pre><?php var_dump($tags); ?></pre><?php
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter. Good to learn something new about the terms. Bedankt.